# How do I initialize values from two classes in one object in the main function? C++

Tags: c++, class, object, header

I'm trying to initialize variables from two classes in one object.

For example, in the main function, I have:

```
Worker Object("Kenny Smith",23425,"1/2/2012", "Third", 1, 12.00);
```

In the worker class, I have the function:

```
Worker::Worker(Store Name, Store Num, Store Date, string Shift, int ShiftNumber, double Rate)
{
    Store name = Name;
    Store number = Num;
    Store date = Date;
    shift = Shift;
    shiftnumber = ShiftNumber;
    rate = Rate;
}
```

When I try to compile the main function, it gives me the error that "no instance of constructor Worker::Worker matches the argument list", because name, number, and date are from the Store class. I've included the Store header in the Worker class.

How will I make it work without separating the functions?

The constructor takes a string from the Store class "Kenny Smith", an integer from the Store class 23425, a string from the Store class "1/2/2012", another string from the worker class  "Third", an integer from the worker class 1, and a double from the worker class 12.00.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The details that aee needed are precisely a [mcve]. Please read carefully what [mcve] means.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. If you need to pass a store, your constructor should take a Store object. If you need to pass a string, a number and another string, then your constructor should take those.

Comment: Worker constructor takes a bunch of Store arguments, you construct one using only strings which can't be done unless you've got other code there that should allow you to. I don't think anyone understands until you post more code.

Comment: The constructor takes a string from the Store class "Kenny Smith", an integer from the Store class 23425, a string from the Store class "1/2/2012", another string from the worker class  "Third", an integer from the worker class 1, and a double from the worker class 12.00.

Comment: You REALLY need to show your Store class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that your **Store** class takes string inputs.

So, I guess this should work

```
Worker Object("Kenny Smith", "23425","1/2/2012", "Third", 1, 12.00);
```

Note the second argument is now a string.

**Edit:** Based on the comment

```
class Store
{
  public:
  Store(string name, int num, string data) { ... }
  Store(string name) { ... }
  Store(int num) { ... }
}
```

I would advise reading a C++ book to understand how constructors work.

**Edit**

```
class Store
{
     string name_;
     int num_;
     int date_;

  public:
      Store(string name, int num, string date) { ... }
      Store(string name) { ... }
      Store(int num) { ... }

     const string& name() const { return name_ };
     string& name() {return name_};
}
```

Now from your Worker class

```
Worker(Store a, .... )
{
    a.name() = string("ABC");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. It is an integer.

Comment: The function on its own is Store(string Name, int Num, string Date);

Comment: Then you should pass Worker Object ( Store("Kenny Smith", num, date), .... ).   Or you should define constructors in the Store class that can initialize the class members using string as well as integer arguments.

Comment: I've tried that as well, but it still gives me the same error. Also, is it possible to initialize a Store class members from the Worker class?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to make a constructor in the Store class that way, but then it will make the constructor I wrote in the main question unnecessary. I wanted to include variables from the Store class in the Worker class.

Comment: Nevermind. I had it like this from the start but I was trying to do it a different way. I'll just do it like this.

Comment: "Is it possible to initialize a Store class member from the worker class?". Yes, define get/set methods in the Store class. See re-edit.